# Generating a list of categorical variables where categorical count is normally distributed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics, normal-distribution

I aim to generate some synthetic data of 1000 rows (to be represented in a `pd.DataFrame` object) populated with a set of categorical variables.

Suppose I have a dict object of all possible categorical variables which can exist.

The list is sorted in priority order, with `'Aaa'` being highest priority and `'NR'`
being lowest priority.

```
credit_score_types = {
    'Aaa':0,
    'Aa1':1,
    'Aa2':2,
    'Aa3':3,
    'A1':4,
    'A2':5,
    'A3':6,
    'Baa1':7,
    'Baa2':8,
    'Baa3':9,
    'Ba1':10,
    'Ba2':11,
    'Ba3':12,
    'B1':13,
    'B2':14,
    'B3':15,
    'Caa':16,
    'Ca':17,
    'C':18,
    'e, p':19,
    'WR':20,
    'unsolicited':21,
    'NR':22
}
```

The `dict` object `key` with the *median* `value` will represent the "peak" of the **Normal Distribution**.

In this case `'Ba2'` will be the "peak" of the **Normal Distribution**.

**The expected outcome:**

To randomly assign a `pd.DataFrame` with 1000 rows (or a populated `list` with length 1000) using categorical variables from the above `dict` object. The assignment of categorical variables will follow a Normal Distribution.

`'Baa2'` will have the highest count.

If a bar chart is plotted with the count of each categorical occurrence, I would observe a graph of normally distributed shape (similar to below).

[image: Graph to illustrate the expected shape when plotting the categorical variables.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal distribution is continuous and not categorical. You might consider binning normally distributed data with intervals that have width 1.0: i.e. 'Baa2' which has a peak of 11 will actually count all normally distributed values in the interval [10.5, 11.5], 'Baa1' will count all values in the interval [9.5, 10.5]... 'Aaa' will count all values in the interval [-0.5, 0.5], and so on...

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

credit_score_types = {
    'Aaa':0,
    'Aa1':1,
    'Aa2':2,
    'Aa3':3,
    'A1':4,
    'A2':5,
    'A3':6,
    'Baa1':7,
    'Baa2':8,
    'Baa3':9,
    'Ba1':10,
    'Ba2':11,
    'Ba3':12,
    'B1':13,
    'B2':14,
    'B3':15,
    'Caa':16,
    'Ca':17,
    'C':18,
    'e, p':19,
    'WR':20,
    'unsolicited':21,
    'NR':22
}

# generate normally distributed data, fix random state 
np.random.seed(42)
mu, sigma = credit_score_types['Ba2'], 5
X = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

counts, bins = np.histogram(X, bins = np.linspace(-0.5, 22.5, 23))

# create a new dictionary of category names and counts
data = dict(zip(credit_score_types.keys(), counts))
ax.bar(data.keys(), data.values())
plt.xticks(rotation = 'vertical')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how you estimated sigma = 5? thanks :)

Comment: I chose sigma = 5 arbitrarily just as a way of guaranteeing that every category had some counts. To get a distribution more like the histogram you showed with more values clustered around the mean/median, you would need a smaller sigma - I would guess that a sigma of around 2 would approximate the distribution you provided.

A good way to estimate sigma is to use the fact that about 68% of the data should be ± 1 standard deviation of the mean.